# Function of Jointly Distributed and Convolution

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, random-variables

Looking into the continuous case of the sum of jointly distributed RVs in an example in my textbook and there are a few steps missing that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete RVs, and $Z=X+Y$

$F_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f(x,y)dydx$

It then says "we make the change of variables $y=v-x$ to get

$F_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^zf(x,v-x)dvdx$

This is where my brain stops following.  How does the upper limit of the inner integral become just $z$?  I can't seem to follow how the change of variable gets us to that.  Thanks for any explanation!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper limit written for the inner integral is the value of $y$ at that upper limit (that is, the inner intergral is the $dy$ integral).  The value of $y$ at the upper limit is $z-x$.

You are changing variables such that the new inner integral is over $dv$.
When $y = v-x$, we have $v = y+x$.  SAO when $y=z-x$, you have $v = (z-x) + x = z$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I knew it was simple but I just couldn't get it.  I'm studying for a huge comprehensive masters exam and I must be at the point where I need to take a break!